# Password match confirmation

Tags: javascript, formvalidation-plugin, password-confirmation

I'm trying to build a form that checks to make sure my pin and pswd match for a form. But not sure what I'm missing. I'm a little young to the WebDev world and I have spent a stupid amount of time trying to figure out something that should really be simple (in my head). I've tried this 5 different ways and keep dumbing it down. Here is something i essentially copied from someone else and it doesn't work for me. Any tips? Just need to get the two inputs to check if they match essentially. FYI: my file that I'm working on IS called initialsetup3SANDBOX.php (not sure if that matters).

```js
function myFunction() {
  var pass1 = document.getElementById("pass1").value;
  var pass2 = document.getElementById("pass2").value;
  if (pass1 != pass2) {
    //alert("Passwords Do not match");
    document.getElementById("pass1").style.borderColor = "#E34234";
    document.getElementById("pass2").style.borderColor = "#E34234";
  } else if {
    alert("Passwords Match!!!");
    document.getElementById("regForm").submit();
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>

  <form id="regform" action="/initialsetup3SANDBOX.php" method="post" onsubmit="return myFunction();">
    <input id="pass1" type="password" placeholder="Password" style="border-radius:7px; border:2px solid #dadada;"><br>
    <input id="pass2" type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" style="border-radius:7px; border:2px solid #dadada;"><br>
  </form>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What is the result you are getting?

Comment: `else if {` is not correct syntax, it should be `else if (*condition*) {` or just `else {`

Comment: nothing. not getting errors. i just click submit and nothing happens.

Answer (score 2):

3 things.

- `<input type="submit" value="Submit" />` should be wrapped into form
  tag, then only the form will submit.
- You are supposed to use `else` not `else if`.
- Also, You have to `return false`. when the password doesn't match.
  otherwise, the form action will happen anyway.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var pass1 = document.getElementById("pass1").value;
  var pass2 = document.getElementById("pass2").value;
  if (pass1 != pass2) {
    //alert("Passwords Do not match");
    document.getElementById("pass1").style.borderColor = "#E34234";
    document.getElementById("pass2").style.borderColor = "#E34234";
    return false;
  } else {
    alert("Passwords Match!!!");
    document.getElementById("regForm").submit();
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="regform" action="/initialsetup3SANDBOX.php" method="post" onsubmit="return myFunction();">
    <input id="pass1" type="password" placeholder="Password" style="border-radius:7px; border:2px solid #dadada;"><br>
    <input id="pass2" type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" style="border-radius:7px; border:2px solid #dadada;"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```